# Understanding for-comprehension

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I have the following traits:

```
trait Command
trait Status
trait Tr{
    def getOpt(id: Long): Option[Status]
}
```

and the following maps:

```
private val chains: mutable.Map[Long, Tr] = mutable.HashMap()
private val commandsId: mutable.Map[Command, Long] = mutable.HashMap()
private val commands: mutable.Map[Long, Command] = mutable.HashMap()
```

I want to implement method:

```
def getStatus(cmd: Command) = commandsId.get(cmd).flatMap(chains.get).flatMap{tr => 
    tr.status(id) //fail, Id was lost at commandsId.get(cmd) step
}
```

Is there a compact form of writing this? I suppose for-comprehension would help, but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   commandsId.get(cmd)
     .flatMap { id =>
        chains.get(id).map(_.status(id))
     }
```

Or, with `for` comprehension:

```
  for {
     id <- commandsId.get(cmd)
     tr <- chains.get(id)
     status <- tr.status(id)
  } yield status
```

Comment: Very interesting, thanks much. AFAIK for-comprehension is just sugar. Could you please explain to which it actually compiles?

Comment: @St.Antario you can check this yourself with the compiler flag `-Xprint:parser`